# Lazy evaluation in R leads to unexpected results if the environment changes between the time the object was created and the time it is evaluated

Tags: r, openxlsx

openxlsx in its current version 4.2.4 overwrites digits precision from default 7 to 22. This results in unexpected behavior, if you try to write a lazy evaluating data.frame using writeData.

```
library(openxlsx)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

wb <- createWorkbook()
sheet <- addWorksheet(wb,"Sheet")
data.frame(a=55.7) %>% mutate(a=a%>%format(nsmall=1)) %>% writeData(wb,sheet,.)
saveWorkbook(wb,"test.xlsx")
```

You may see, that the workbook contains not the expected string "55.7", but more decimals. This is because in global environment format works with 7 digits, so format(55.7)=="55.7", but within writeData it evaluates as

format(55.7)=="55.700000000000003"

This is not a issue of floating-point math, but an issue of changing environments. format uses as a default value "digits=getOption("digits")". Default is 7, within writeData it's 22. That's all there is, nothin special about that.

I wanted to know, why format(55.7) does not get evaluated within the context of global environment.

Comment: This is not an issue of displaying or formatting. I looked into the XML of these files and the numbers `55.70000000000000284217` and `57.7` were written by the R function.

Comment: this is almost-certainly a case of IEE 754 floating point aliasing; see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Yeah, obviously, but this is not the point. My question is, how/why/where the character gets casted to a floating point again. Please note the edit and see the correct string "55.7" in the data.frame.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The expression is lazily evaluated with the digits options in the current environment. openxlsx::writeData somewhere uses 17 digits, whereas the default value is 7.

```
library(magrittr)

f <- function(x) {
  rlang::scoped_options(digits=17)
  x$a
}
data.frame(a=format(1234.1)) %>% f()

> 1234.0999999999999

df <- data.frame(a=format(1234.1))
df %>% f()

> 1234.1
```

Edit: Developers from openxlsx confirmed the behaviour. They solved it by forcing the evaluation of their input data.frame before changing any environment variables in their [fix](https://github.com/ycphs/openxlsx/commit/91578c25e7eeb037ef500237d55a62524b8e46be).

---

Here is the [link to my next question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69388892/how-do-i-force-evaluation-of-a-hanging-r-expression) which shows the exact same unexpected behavior, but without using numbers.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it's a feature (or bug) of `openxlsx`:

- The R objects were identical
- This is not an issue of displaying or formatting. I looked into the XML of these files and the numbers 55.70000000000000284217 and 57.7 were written by the R function
- Replacing `openxlsx` with `writexl` eliminates this discrepancy

Comment: Is openxlsx deprecated? Switching to another library will be a lot of work.

Comment: @TobiasHofmann No it isn't, you may want to [address the author](https://github.com/ycphs/openxlsx/issues).